# How to rotate an image without using OpenCV functions? (using Linear, Qubic interpolation)

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to rotate an image without using the OpenCV function.

[image]

I want to do it pixel by pixel with interpolation (nearest neighbors & linear & cubic) and later I would like to do it with a rotation matrix.

Problems:

1. Can't understand how to implement the interpolations. Even one example with the Qubic will help me.
2. for some reason the left pixels in the original image are sent to the right side in the rotated image and it seems not right for the rotation (should be black pixels).
3. Add an extra option (but not a must) to rotate the image from the center of the image. (and not from (0,0) which is the top left of the image by default)

The original image:

[image]

My code: (AFTER UPDATE 1)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"

using namespace std;

enum interpolation_type{
    INTERPOLATION_CUBIC,
    INTERPOLATION_LINEAR,
    INTERPOLATION_NEAREST_NEIGHBOR
};


void Interpolation_Calculator(const cv::Point& srcPixel,cv::Point2i& dstPixel, interpolation_type type){
    // The origin pixels for the currPixel in the newImage depends on the interpolation type
    int originX = 0;
    int originY = 0;

    if(type == INTERPOLATION_NEAREST_NEIGHBOR)
    {
        originX = (int)round(srcPixel.x);
        originY = (int)round(srcPixel.y);
    }
    else if(type == INTERPOLATION_LINEAR){

    }
    else if (type == INTERPOLATION_CUBIC){

    }

    dstPixel.x = originX;
    dstPixel.y = originY;
}

void RotationFunction(const cv::Mat& src,cv::Mat& dst, int angle, interpolation_type type){
    // The pixels in the new image we want to find right origin pixel for his value.
    double rotatedX;
    double rotatedY;

    double toRadian = 3.141592653589/180;

    for(int r=0;r<dst.rows;r++)
     {
      for(int c=0;c<dst.cols;c++)
      {
          rotatedX = r*cos(angle * toRadian) - c*sin(angle * toRadian);
          rotatedY = r*sin(angle * toRadian) + c*cos(angle * toRadian);
          
          cv::Point rotatedPixel(rotatedX,rotatedY);
          cv::Point2i originPixel;
          Interpolation_Calculator(rotatedPixel,originPixel,type);
          //cv::Vec3b vector(0,0,0);

          // Checking if the Interpolation calculations crossed the boundaries
          if(originPixel.x < 0 || originPixel.x > src.cols - 1 || originPixel.y < 0 || originPixel.y > src.rows - 1)
              dst.at<cv::Vec3b>(cv::Point(r, c)) = 0;
          else { // In case everything is good
              cv::Vec3b currPixel = src.at<cv::Vec3b>(originPixel);
              dst.at<cv::Vec3b>(cv::Point(r, c)) = currPixel;
          }

      }
    }
}

int main() {
    cv::Mat img = cv::imread("../lion.jpeg");
    cv::Mat rotatedImage(img.rows,img.cols,CV_8UC3);
    // Rotating
    RotationFunction(img,rotatedImage,25,INTERPOLATION_NEAREST_NEIGHBOR);
    // End of Rotating

    // Show the images
    cv::imshow("window1",img);
    cv::imshow("window2",rotatedImage);
    cv::waitKey(0);
    // End of Show the images

    return 0;
}
```

Bad Output:

[image]

Comment: why you delete the previous question? (not sure it's you, maybe it's closed by others).

Comment: and I think you should do interpolation and rotate **separately** then, if only necessary, merge them.

Comment: @appleapple Thanks for the advice, but unfortunately I need help with the interpolation, I'm not sure how to do it even with closest neighbor..

Comment: You are iterating over pixels of original not rotated. Rotated pixels have to be interpolated from possibly multiple of original.

Comment: you calculate, for every source pixel, a destination pixel. that's wrong. you need to calculate, for every *destination* pixel, the *source* pixel (sub-pixel precision) it should have come from. that's how everyone does it, including OpenCV. yes, that would involve inverting the affine transformation you desire. -- the wrap-around is probably due to `Mat::at` not checking bounds (and neither do you...) and instead just calculating the linear offset... which causes this behavior.

Comment: Interpolation ist just about how to handle subpixel positions. Once you transform from a dst pixel to the src pixel you will likely hit a subpixel position (like x=4.742 and y=104.395) and now you can round to x=5 and y=104 or you can choose 0.395*(0.742*pix(5,105) + 0.248*pix(4,105)) + 0.605* (0.742*pix(5,104) + 0.248*pix(4,104)) for example.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I have updated my code (Update 1) and the output. it seems like I am on the right track, But I still messed up. for some reason the right side has only black pixels. In addition I am not sure if the rotation is to the correct direction (because of the image (0,0) center default.

Comment: @Micka I got your first example (Nearest Neighbor) and even updated my code (Update 1) according to it, thanks. but still I got bad output, and I didn't understand your second example, is it bilinear interpolation? how do I calculate it?

Comment: @appleapple thanks, I did a separate function to the interpolation. is it fine? (I have updated my code. update 1)

Comment: What's bad in your output? Looks reasonable to me. Which rounding type did you use? Not 100% sure but second example could be bilinear. First linear in one direction, then linear in the other direction.

Comment: cv::Point(r, c) is wrong, it must be cv::Point(r, c) sincr c is column (x) and r is row (y). Same for the rest of your formula I think.

Comment: @Micka Thanks! fixing the rows and colums (had to change it in the loops too) fixed the black rectangle in the right side of the output image. Now I need to understand how to do the BiLinear/BiQubic interpolation.

Comment: have a look at the formulas and detail them out in a manual example. For example in biliear, draw a quad on a sheet of paper and give every corner A,B,C,D some "property". Then for example if you want to have supixel position exactly at point A you obviously get property of 1*A + 0*B + 0*C + 0*D. If you are at 50% between A and B you'll get 0.5*A + 0.5*B. If you are at 50% in x and y you'll get 0.25*A + 0.25*B + 0.25*C + 0.25*D and if you are at alpha in x and beta in y you'll get `X1 = alpha*B + (1-alpha)*A` and `X2 = alpha*D + (1-alpha*C)` linearly interpolated in X direction for both rows

Comment: and then `beta*X2 + (1-beta)*X1` linearly interpolated in Y direction. So bilinear means just 2 times linear interpolation. Interpolated in each direction one after the other. The image in wikipedia explains it quite well.